# For loop only stores final result in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, store

I am trying to run a for loop in R which stores the result in a list. I cannot store the data in a matrix as my outputs vary in length. For example, the following code produces a list with all entries as 'NULL' apart from the last section.

```
for(i in 1:n) {
  time <- list()
  time[[i]] <- (sample(1:96, wb[i], replace=T, prob=weekday[,1]))
print(time)
}
```

However, if I do this, the result is what I want, but it is not stored, so I cannot use it later.

```
for(i in 1:n) {
   print(sample(1:96, wb[i], replace=T, prob=weekday[,1]))
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are re-initializing `time` every time through your loop: `time <- list()`. Move that outside the loop. (Although growing objects like this will become very slow very quickly in R.)

Comment: Walk through your loop.  When i is 1 you store into time an empty list then put some stuff into the first element. When i is 2 you store into time an empty list (note this part) and then put in the second spot some stuff. What is in the first spot?

Comment: I just thought of that as you posted the response. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For added fun (and efficiency) you can try

```
time <- lapply(1:n, function(i) sample(1:96, wb[i], replace=T, prob=weekday[,1]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much more efficient :)

Comment: @shana246 be careful with assuming apply functions are more efficient.  They're more efficient with respect to amount of typed code but they aren't necessarily more efficient than a well written loop because that's all apply functions are is wrappers for loops.  I say that they aren't necessarily more efficient because they do make some simple data conversions that make whatever is going on in the loop more efficient that might get overlooked if doing an explicit loop.  For example apply will convert a dataframe into a matrix which is quicker to iterate through.

Comment: @shana246 All that being said, apply functions are the preferred way to loop through simplish functions.  My only point is that there seems to be some misconceptions that apply functions are *faster* than explicit for loops when they're just wrappers for loops.